# ASP.NET MVC EF Core, Property Access in View while on selected ID for different Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I´m having an issue where I have three models as show below: `Person`, `Competence` with `PersonCompetence` between them. My current controller method gets an Id from previous page and shows that person with a list of this person's `Competence` and `Level`. In this View however I want to have a **POST** for new `Competence`. So at the same time you are adding a new one and you can see which ones you already have.

With the controller method I have now I can access the `PersonCompetence` and `Competence` when showing the list.
I dont have access to the `Competence` properties for `asp-for="Competence"` marked ###### in the View for `AddComp`.

- I need the `ID` of person for **POST** to right person
- I need the `CompetenceType` for **POST** to that property
- I need `PersonCompetence` to show the list of current `PersonCompetence`.

I get that with the current `@model CompetenceRadar.Models.Person` I only reach Person properties.

I have looked at having a `ViewModel` with access to all tables with an `IEnumerable` for each table, but this breaks my current Controller when I search for the Id of the person showing. I have switched the `@model` in the View, but then I can't access Person ID/name.

So how do I access the `Competence` properties , list one person and get a list of `PersonCompetences` for that Person.

Please tell me if you want me to clarify something.
I don't need working code, just something to point me in the right direction for a solution.

- Is it a ViewModel?
- Can I POST without the `asp-for`attribute?

**Models**

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonCompetences> PersonCompetences { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
public class PersonCompetence
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }         // FK
    public int CompetenceID { get; set; }         // FK
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public Competece Competence { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Competence
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompetenceType { get; set; }
    public string CompetenceCategory { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonCompetence> PersonCompetences { get; set; }
}
```

**`AddComp` Kontroller function**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> AddComp(int? id)
{
    var person = await _context.Personer
        .Include(pk => pk.PersonCompetences)
        .ThenInclude(k => k.Competence)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

    return View(person);
}
```

**`View_AddComp` View for `AddComp`**

```
@model CompetenceRadar.Models.Person

<h1>AddComp</h1>

<div class="row">
    <form asp-action="AddComp">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="#############" class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
            <input asp-for="#############" class="form-control col-sm-4" />
            <span class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-dark" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model.PersonCompetences)
{
    <div class="row py-2 rounded" style="background-color:lightslategray">
        <div class="col-sm-3 pt-2">@item.Competence.CompetenceType</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 pt-2">@item.Niva</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 pt-2">@item.Competence.CompetenceCategory</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a class="btn btn-dark mr-1" role="button" asp-area="" asp-controller="Competence" asp-action="UpdateLevel" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-dark mr-1" role="button" asp-area="" asp-controller="Competence" asp-action="DeleteComp" asp-route-id="@item.CompetenceID">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If I can make a personal recommendation: you should consider sticking to english in your code. It is best practice basically internationally.

Comment: Yes, great suggestion. I'll change that right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple anwser is that I needed a ViewModel with all three Models

```
public class ExampleViewModel {

    public Person person { get; set; }
    public PersonCompetence personCompetence { get; set; }
    public Competence competence { get; set; }}
```

This alows me to access the different values for ID, CompetenceType and a List for of the current PersonCompetence.

[What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)